# c3js Stacked Bar chart from json array

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, bar-chart, c3.js

Guys this is the problem: I have a timeseries  stacked bar chart written with c3js, and it works really nice. but I still need to create a stacked bar chart with the same data **BUT** as a category chart...

my Json looks like this:

```
{"product":"acucar5kg","bundle":0,"units":5342,"production":26710,"label":"acuuki 5kg","line":"Empacotamento 1","date":"2017-10-02"}
```

and my original chart is like this:

- x-axis: date
- y-axis: production
- groups: label

my objective is to have

- x-axis: line
- y-axis: production
- groups: label

to make it simple my original code is over here: [code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a53xhu53/)
and cheating real quick for anyone to understand what i really want...  here is the mockup [image: new chart]

Save me plz !! =*

p.s. feel free to smite and bash my code... i`m not a good JS dev... yet!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, took me some time but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0fhb39p7/1/) is a fiddle what do you need. To works I did:

Change the line in `return d.line;` for the `nestedData` object and the `obj.line = entry.key;` for the `formatedData` object. Also make changes to the properties  `x: 'line',` and the type `type: 'category'` in the generate method.

Check and tell me if that works for you.

Comment: Rokum!  GREAT SUCCESS! thanks for your answer!  that solved flawlessly!